# I get this error: "'3' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path." and it only happens when I add validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model-view-controller, model, controller

This is the error I get.
[image: This is the error I get]

This is my model code.

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pages

  validates :name,
  :presence => true,
  :length => { :maximum => 255 }


  scope :visible, lambda { where(:visible => true) }
  scope :invisible, lambda { where(:visible => false) }
  scope :sorted, lambda { order("subjects.position ASC")}
  scope :newest_first, lambda { order("subject.created_at DESC") }
  scope :search, lambda { |query|
    where(["name LIKE ?", "%#{query}%"])
  }
end
```

I noticed that it's saying something about my create action. So here's that:

```
class SubjectsController < ApplicationController

    layout "admin"

  def index
    @subjects = Subject.sorted  
  end

  def show
    @subject = Subject.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @subject = Subject.new({:name => 'Default'})
    @subject_count = Subject.count + 1
  end

  def create
    # Instantiate a new object using form parameters
    @subject = Subject.new(subject_params)
    # Save the object
    if @subject.save
        # If save succeeds, redirect to the index
        flash[:notice] = "The subject was created successfully."
        redirect_to(:action => 'index')
      else
        @subject_count = Subject.count + 1
        render(new)
    end
  end

  def edit
    @subject = Subject.find(params[:id])
    @subject_count = Subject.count
  end

  def update
    # Find an existing object using form parameters
    @subject = Subject.find(params[:id])
    # Update the object
    if @subject.update_attributes(subject_params)
        # If save succeeds, redirect to the show
        flash[:notice] = "The subject was updated successfully."
        redirect_to(:action => 'show', :id => @subject.id)
      else 
        # If update fails, redisplay the form so user can fix problem.
        @subject_count = Subject.count
        render('edit')
    end
  end

  def delete
   @subject = Subject.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    subject = Subject.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:notice] = "The subject '#{subject.name}' was deleted successfully."
    redirect_to(:action => 'index')
  end

  private

    def subject_params
      # same as using "params[:subject]", except that it:
      # -raises an error if :subject is not present
      # -allows listed attributes to be mass-assigned
      params.require(:subject).permit(:name, :position, :visible)
    end

end
```

If I take the validations off it works, but then I can create the subject without a name. I noticed that if I add a subject the number in the paranthesis '3' moves up. I wonder if it has something to do with the select form. Here's the form:

```
    <%= error_messages_for(@subject) %>

<table summary="Subject form fields" class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th><%= f.label(:name, "Name") %></th>
        <td><%= f.text_field(:name) %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><%= f.label(:position) %></th>
        <td><%= f.select(:position, 1..@subject_count) %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><%= f.label(:visible) %></th>
        <td><%= f.check_box(:visible) %></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Update: I'm adding the index view per request.

```
<% @page_title = 'Subjects' %>

<div class="subjects show">

    <h2>Subjects</h2>

    <%= link_to("Add New Subject", {:action => 'new'}, :class => 'action new btn btn-default') %>

    <table class="listing table table-hover" summary="Subject list">
        <tr class="header">
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Subject</th>
            <th>Visible</th>
            <th>Pages</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
        <% @subjects.each do |subject| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= subject.position %></td>
            <td><%= subject.name %></td>
            <td class="center"><%= subject.visible ? 'Yes' : 'No' %></td>
            <td class="center"><%= subject.pages.size %></td>
            <td class="actions">
                <%= link_to("Show", {:action => 'show', :id => subject.id}, :class => 'action show') %>
                <%= link_to("Edit", {:action => 'edit', :id => subject.id}, :class => 'action edit') %>
                <%= link_to("Delete", {:action => 'delete', :id => subject.id}, :class => 'action delete') %>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: what exactly happens here "if I add a subject the number in the paranthesis '3' moves up."

Comment: @Abhinay Not sure. I assume that it correlates with the position or the id number.

Comment: show your `index` view please

Comment: you might want to check the syntax for `select` helper here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#select-boxes-for-dealing-with-models

Comment: @Abhinay where would the count method be? Controller? or View? Thanks for the select suggestion. I do want to add that the error happened prior to using the select helper. Maybe that might help narrow it down.

Comment: @PudparK my bad, `count` is a built in method from ActiveRecord  :)

Comment: @nobilik I've added the index.

Comment: @PudparK can you please add the console log. look like error is due to this method http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/PartialRenderer/partial_path

Comment: are you sure `render(new)` in `else` of `create` action works fine?

Comment: Abhinay is right. `render :new` or `render 'new'`

Comment: @Abhinay Bingo!!! Thanks a lot! I'm glad to know that I was on the right track. I knew it had something to do with the create action. I guess it was throwing an error, because the else option wasn't rendering. I'll mark it as the answer as soon as I figure out how to do so. Thanks again!

Comment: @PudparK I am glad it worked , will post an answer soon. happy coding!!

Comment: @PudparK at first he must add the answer)) for now it's just comment

Comment: @PudparK yep writing it.

Comment: @Abhinay thanks for the help. The coding community seems to be real helpful. I would go crazy without it.

Comment: @PudparK Yeah same goes for me. thats true. specially people on SO have been really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

due to a syntax error for the partial on the `else` part of `create` action, active model was throwing an exception(http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/ActionView/PartialRenderer/partial_path)

```
def create
   #few lines escaped....
  else
    @subject_count = Subject.count + 1
    render(new) # <-- Error
end
```

It should be either `render :new` or `render 'new'` as mentioned by [Nobilik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5493147/nobilik). your method should look like:

```
def create
   #few lines escaped....
  else
    @subject_count = Subject.count + 1
    render :new # for best practice
end
```